# Kivy create widget by code which loads a .kv file

Tags: python, popup, kivy

I want to create a pop-up tutorial for when the user opens the app for the first time. As I wanted this tutorial to be as separate as possible from the code from the rest of the app (and only load when the tutorial is used) I separated the code like this:

In the same folder:

- foo.py
- foo.kv
- learnkanji_tut.py
- learnkanji_tut.kv

### Edit foo.py

foo.py (which has in the .kv file id: lfunc):

```
class LayoutFunctioning(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(LayoutFunctioning, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        tutorial = 1

        if tutorial:
            Clock.schedule_once(lambda dt: self.tutwidget())

    def tutwidget(self):         
        import learnkanji_tut
        tutpop = learnkanji_tut.TutInteraction()
        self.ids.lfunc.add_widget(tutpop)
```

learnkanji_tut.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/kivy
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from os.path import join, dirname


class TutInteraction(Popup):
    curdir = dirname(__file__)
    Builder.load_file(join(curdir, 'learnkanji_tut.kv'))
    tut_text = "Tut"

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.title = 'Tutorial Popup'
        self.auto_dismiss = 'False'
        super(TutInteraction, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        print("Tutorial loaded")
        self.tut_step = 0  # Current step in the tutorial
```

learnkanji_tut.kv:

```
#:kivy 1.9.1

<TutInteraction>:
    id: tutpop

    BoxLayout:
        ScrollView:
            size_hint_y: 0.8
            text: "test"

        BoxLayout:
            size_hint_y: 0.2

            Button:
                size_hint_x: 0.3
                text: "Skip"

            Button:
                size_hint_x: 0.7
                text: "Next"
```

### Error:

`self.ids.lfunc.add_widget(tutpop)
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 757, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__ (kivy\properties.c:11882)
 AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'`

### Question:

What am I doing wrong? Why can I not add a popup widget like this?
Following the docs: https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.popup.html, Popup should have: `Popup.title and Popup.content`.

I have a title (`self.title = 'Tutorial Popup'`) and content (the .kv file). So do I do something wrong here or somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

From @inclement in the IRC channel #kivy: "Don't use add_widget with a Popup, call its .open() method"

So this means:

```
if tutorial:
    import learnkanji_tut
    tutpop = learnkanji_tut.TutInteraction()
    tutpop.open()
```

p.s. It seems that `Clock.schedule_once()` is not necessary.